Finding the set for random variable transformations
I'm reading through the book "All of Statistics", and in section 2.12, regarding Transformations of Several Random Variables, the author lists three steps for finding the transformation. I was struggling with this even with univariate transformations. The text has the following:
Given that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, $\text{let }Z = r(X, Y)$.
The first step listed to perform a transformation is:

For each $z$, find the set $A_z = \{(x,y) : r(x, y) \le z \}$.

The author then uses this set to find the CDF.
$$
\begin{align}
F_Z &= \mathbb{P}(Z \le z)\\
&= \mathbb{P}(r(X, Z) \le z)\\
&= \mathbb{P}(\{(x,y); r(x,y) \le z\})\\
&= \iint_{A_z}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\;dx\;dy
\end{align}
$$
Finally, he finds the PDF via differentiating the CDF.
I seem to be stuck on the first step. Can someone explain a bit more intuitively how this would work in practice?

The first step is to identify where $Z\leq z$ is. Then you integrate over that region to get the probability, which is nothing but the distribution function. Then you differentiate it to get the density. This is a crude but simple breakdown
